# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter checking if query completed successfully

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` (part of [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)) to load Firebase data into a `RecyclerView`, but no where in the documentation or online can I find a way to detect if it failed. For example, if a user has a slow connection or no connection at all and the query failed to complete, how could you detect that? Even in the sample code they have doesn't seem to do any error checking with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries don't fail, except for lack of permission to read the location of the query.  Listeners will silently retry until a connection is established.

Comment: Odd...my application works great on 4g and other WiFi networks, but doesn't work on my slow WiFi connection, even after leaving it open for a while. I figured the request timed out...

Comment: There are no timeouts.

Comment: I suppose there must be a different issue with my application that's causing it to not load on my WiFi for some reason. Thanks for letting me know.